# Making global mutable variables that are available to all classes in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am developing a game which needs variables that need to be accessed by different classes. I wanted to know if there is a way to make global mutable variables with Objective C?

Comment: Why don't you encapsulate them in a class? You can make it a singleton if they're truly global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach is to provide a singleton class which provides access to the required variables.  And rather than exposing a raw variable that is mutated directly by the caller, you should really encapsulate the operations.  Having true global variables creates too much coupling and is a bad code smell.

For example, a singleton lets you write this:

```
[[NetworkTrafficStats instance] addNetworkTraffic:bytes_sent];
```

which is much better to maintain than:

```
extern unsigned gTotalBytesSent;
//...
gTotalBytesSent += bytes_sent;
```

Worth reading:

- [Singleton Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028909/singleton-design)
- [The Objective-C Singleton](http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/)
- [ADC: Singletons](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html)

Answer (score 2):

There's no problem creating global mutable variables in Objective-C.

In a header file:

```
extern NSMutableArray *gMyArray;
extern NSMutableDictionary *gMyDictionary;
```

In your application delegate source file:

```
NSMutableArray *gMyArray;
NSMutableDictionary *gMyDictionary;
```

In applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
gMyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
gMyDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Then just #import the header file in every source file you want to access the global.